# How to delete listview item from the sqlite database when the delete button is clicked in a created dialog?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
package com.dharquissandas.budget;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.DialogAction; 
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.color.ColorChooserDialog;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.data;

public class tab3expense extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "tab3expense";
DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private ListView mListView;
View rootView;
Cursor expensedata;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3expense, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewexpense);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {

    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");
    expensedata = mDatabaseHelper.getexpenseData();
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, expensedata, new String[]{DatabaseHelper.EXPENSE_AMOUNT}, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    mListView.setAdapter(sca);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            int csrpos = expensedata.getPosition();
            expensedata.moveToPosition(i);
            displayNoteDate(
                    expensedata.getString(expensedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.EXPENSE_NOTES)),
                    expensedata.getString(expensedata.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.EXPENSE_DATE)));
            expensedata.moveToPosition(csrpos);
        }
    });
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    expensedata.close();
}

public void displayNoteDate(String noteContent, String dateValue) {
        MaterialDialog.Builder builder= new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .title("Expense Information")
            .content("Note: "+noteContent+"\nDate: "+ dateValue)
            .positiveText("edit")
            .negativeText("delete")
            .neutralText("close")
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"EDIT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .onNeutral(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"CLOSE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"DELETE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
}

}
```

delete part of Database Helper:

```
    public Integer deleteexpenseData(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    }
```

I have created the dialog which when clicked on the specific listview item shows extra information that is also present about that value. As you can see I have a delete button but do not know how to call the delete function. If you can help me with references to my code that would be great because I am fairly new to android programming. I have added more of my code so you can tell me what to do.

Comment: `does not seem to work` is not enough… what have you tried, what error do you see, what’s in the log?

Comment: I get the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: This means your editText is null, which has nothing to do with SQL. Probably your `mAmountExpense`. So either that is null, or `getText` returns null. Java is a null shit-fest so use and abuse `TextUtils.isEmpty(String)` to check for null/empty before you attempt to use a reference.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the list is exactly the same with the SQL data, you can delete them by their ids.
I believe you mark the list row before attempting to delete that row/item. 
Firstly Log the deletedRows variable so as to know the id/position that it holds. If it holds the position, what you need do is to use that position to query your database and delete the sqlite data.

Comment: That is not very helpful to me because I don't know how to do that because I am fairly new to android programming, I would need some code to tell you if something works or not.

Comment: How do you identify the ListView item you want to delete ?

Comment: When I click the listview item it opens a dialog which has the delete button on it

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem has nothing to do with your question. I hope this serves as a lesson to future Stack Overflow readers willing to ask questions.

You spent time thinking how to ask a question about why your delete wasn’t working, without spending time to try or see why wasn’t it working.

When asked a simple question (LOG), you immediately produced the key piece of information: Null Pointer Exception.

You can Google what that is (if you’re not sure) but in essence, you tried to access something that points to nothing. The error message in the log even gives you a hint:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Sounds confusing, but in truth it’s telling you, you tried to access `getText()` on a **null** object reference. A.k.a.: your `mAmountExpense` is probably null. And as such, you can’t access or use it, because it’s null. It points to nothing.

## Why?

Possibly because you didn’t do a `findViewById()` ?

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the trouble I should have just looked it up, I was just stuck on the deleting problem for so long that I thought that was not working